# Why do Pandas DataFrame groups or slices get stale? Are they copies?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

My understanding is that DataFrame groups are slices, which are views into the DataFrame and *not* copies of the DataFrame.  But the following example suggests otherwise:

```py
# Sample DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[('A', 1), ('A', 2), ('B', 5)], columns=('Name', 'Value')).set_index(['Name'])
groupA = df.groupby('Name').get_group('A')  # Isn't this a view into df?
# Let's change the values in the DataFrame corresponding to groupA:
df.loc[df.index == 'A', 'Value'] = groupA.Value.values + 1
```

We have successfully altered the DataFrame.  `df` now returns:

```
      Value
Name       
A         2
A         3
B         5
```

But `groupA` returns the old values:

```
      Value
Name       
A         1
A         2
```

So every time we do a `.groupby` are we actually creating a copy of the sliced DataFrame?

My typical use case for a DataFrame group is as a filter for some operation and assignment.  In this example I want to add 1 to the Values with key `'A'`.  Is there a canonical way to do that without creating a copy of the slice which will serve no purpose?

Comment: Given the description in [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), I'm not sure how it could be assumed that `.groupby` creates a reference back to the original dataframe. Your experiment demonstrates, _My understanding is that DataFrame groups are slices_, is not the case. `.groupby` does not create a copy of a slice. _A groupby operation involves some combination of splitting the object, applying a function, and combining the results_, which _returns a groupby object that contains information about the groups._

Answer (score 0):

Groupby creates a `df` view, but you have attributed it to `groupA`, another variable with a different identifier.
And you have updated only `df`.
So the values from `groupA` weren't changed.

```
# Sample DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[('A', 1), ('A', 2), ('B', 5)], columns=('Name', 'Value')).set_index(['Name'])
print(df)
#       Value
# Name       
# A         1
# A         2
# B         5
print(id(df))
# 140512896695264

# groupA
groupA = df.groupby('Name').get_group('A')  # Isn't this a view into df?
print(groupA)
#       Value
# Name       
# A         1
# A         2
print(id(df.groupby('Name').get_group('A')))
# 140512896694536
print(id(groupA))
# 140512896695096

# Update df
df.loc[df.index == 'A', 'Value'] = groupA.Value.values + 1
print(df)
#       Value
# Name       
# A         2
# A         3
# B         5
print(groupA)
#       Value
# Name       
# A         1
# A         2

# Update groupA
groupA = df.groupby('Name').get_group('A')  
print(groupA)
#       Value
# Name       
# A         2
# A         3
```

Comment: So *assignment of part of the view to a variable* creates a copy of that part?

Comment: I suppose so. Nevertheless in this case you're selecting the values and adding 1 to them, it's not just a slice.